# How to add optional options to VScode running pip install

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image: Running a cell generates the following dialog]

Clicking "Install" generates the following command:

(py310) bash-4.4$ /home/dummy/.venvs/py310/bin/python /mount/dummy/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/shell_exec.py /home/dummy/.venvs/py310/bin/python -m pip install -U ipykernel /tmp/tmp-12835ziykmDvElJGn.log
Executing command in shell >> /home/dummy/.venvs/py310/bin/python -m pip install -U ipykernel

However I need to have additional options added to running of the above command to use internally hosted repo for example:

--trusted-host artifactory.myurl --trusted-host artifactory.myurl.azurewebsites.us -i https://myurl/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-internal/simple

Thanks

I see no options in VSCode settings to add these parameters for running of the pip install.

Answer (score -1):

You can run the command manually in the **terminal** instead of automatically installing it by vscode.

Comment: Not useful as the question is directed at how to do this within VSCode

Comment: @Richard Wheeler Use shortcut "ctrl+~" to call terminal.

Comment: I am quite aware of running it via command line.  The point of the question is where, if possible, to configure in VSCode  so that clicking the button can add the parameters.

Comment: @Richard Wheeler Unfortunately, there are no relevant settings at present. You can only manually input custom code snippets through the terminal. You can submit a feature request on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode).